# unity import texture by script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, import, textures

I try to import a picture into my game by using this code:

```
IEnumerator LoadTileset(){
        WWW www = new WWW ("C:/Users/Public/Documents/Unity Projects/Your RPG/Assets/Tilesets/Terrain.png");
        yield return www;
        if (www.error == null) {
            source = www.texture;
        } else {
            print ("www Error : " + www.error);
        }
    }
```

the file I want to import does exist (if I paste the link Into the Windows explorer, it is opening the picture). The File is from a folder created by script at the application folder but when i Start the Coroutine i get this error:

http://www2.pic-upload.de/img/28671426/Error.png

Does someone of you know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your exact Error but you should always load Resources using the Resource.Load("path/relative/to/Resources/folder") function.

Solutions with absolut paths and not Resource.Load() might work in the Editor, but when Unity compiles, it rearranges your games folder structure and you can't use your paths anymore.

Comment: I tried to use the Resource.Load function but it didnt work for me... It just doesnt find the file I think. I tried it in many ways but no of them worked. It didnt show me any errors... Can you maybe give me an example how to import a Texture which is in the Application.datapath in a folder called "Tilesets"?

Comment: The Resource.Load function can only access stuff located in the "Resources" folder that you need to create in your Assets folder (just in you project folder that you see in unity project pane). You can only reliably load stuff during runtime that is in this folder. The command is used like this:   Resources.Load<Texture>("Tilesets/texture1"); (c#). This loads "texture1" from the Folder "Resources/Tilesets"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WWW to access local files, see the docs:

> Note: When using file protocol on Windows and Windows Store Apps for accessing local files, you have to specify file:/// (with three slashes).

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html